# Unable to update participants using civicrm api?

Tags: drupal, api, participants

Instead of updating the Participant,its creating new participant.I need to change participant status from **registered** to **attended** and vice versa.

```
civicrm_initialize();
  $result = civicrm_api3('Participant', 'create', [
  'id' => $entity_id,
  'contact_id' => $context['civicrm_participant']->contact_id,
  'event_id'   => $context['civicrm_participant']->event_id,
  'status_id' => "Registered",
]);
```

I am executing the above code in the hook_action_info() drupal 7 using views bulk operations & custom entity module

```
function custom_changes_action_info() {
  return array(
     'custom_changes_actions_participant_status_attended_action' => array(
         'type' => 'civicrm_participant',
         'label' => t('Change Participant Status to Attended'),
         'configurable' => FALSE,
         'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
         'triggers' => array('any'),
     ),
      'custom_changes_actions_participant_status_registered_action' => array(
         'type' => 'civicrm_participant',
         'label' => t('Change Participant Status to Registered'),
         'configurable' => FALSE,
         'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
         'triggers' => array('any'),
     ),
  ); 
}

function custom_changes_actions_participant_status_attended_action($entity, $context = array()) {


  $entity_id = $entity->{$info['entity keys']['id']};

  civicrm_initialize();
 $result = civicrm_api3('Participant', 'create', [
  'id' => $entity_id,
  'contact_id' => $context['civicrm_participant']->contact_id,
  'event_id'   => $context['civicrm_participant']->event_id,
  'status_id' => "Attended",
]);
  //drupal_set_message($entity_id. 'entity_id');
 // $base_url = str_replace('_', '-', $context['entity_type']); // civicrm-participant
  //civicrm_entity_drupal_goto($base_url . '/' . $entity_id . '/edit');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are passing $entity_id to id in participant params without checking it to be not empty. If $entity_id is empty then new participant will be created else it will be updated. Make sure your id is set before calling to participant api if you want to update the participant

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Hi @Pradeep , even when it has values it does not work. debugging it further we are using a batch operation, does that have any reason for the api to not work as when I add die() inside function custom_changes_actions_participant_status_attended_action() it changes the status, otherwise it does not

Comment: That sounds different to your original question ... not changing status vs creating new participants.  Can you clarify in the question what you are seeing?